# How can i covert a 3x3 grid from python to tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

SO I have this piece of code and it only prints out in the python shell, I would like to know how I can get the words and put them into a grid using labels in tkinter. Sorry for my lack of explanation.

```
import random
    with open('Words.txt') as f:
        words = random.sample([x.rstrip() for x in f],9)
        grid = [words[i:i +3] for i in range(0, len(words),3)]
        for x,y,z in grid:
            print(x,y,z)
```

Comment: first create `tkinter` application. then create `labels` and use `grid(row=..., column=...)`

Comment: do you know how to use tkinter? what part of the problem are you struggling with? As written, this question is very broad.

Comment: When posting code, put data in the code, as in Steven Summers answer.

Comment: NIGHT
SMOKE
GHOST
TOOTH
ABOUT
CAMEL
BROWN
FUNNY
CHAIR
PRICE

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started. I generally use pack for my projects. But for this I would suggest grid because it allows you to position your labels easily.

```
import tkinter as tk


words = [['Word 1', 'Word 2', 'Word 3'],\
         ['Word 4', 'Word 5', 'Word 6'],\
         ['Word 7', 'Word 8', 'Word 9']]

root = tk.Tk()

for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(words):
    tk.Label(root, text=x).grid(row=i, column=0)
    tk.Label(root, text=y).grid(row=i, column=1)
    tk.Label(root, text=z).grid(row=i, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer using your existing code, in Python 3:

```
import random
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
    with open('Words.txt') as f:
        words = random.sample([x.rstrip() for x in f],9)
        grid = [words[i:i +3] for i in range(0, len(words),3)]
        for i, (x,y,z) in grid:
            Label(root, text=x).grid(row=i, column=0)
            Label(root, text=y).grid(row=i, column=1)
            Label(root, text=z).grid(row=i, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Can't test it for you as don't have sample data but should work.

Comment: The sample data you need, NIGHT
SMOKE
GHOST
TOOTH
ABOUT
CAMEL
BROWN
FUNNY
CHAIR
PRICE

Comment: i get the error, for i, (x,y,z) in grid:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)....... please help